# How to properly check if a table exists in WordPress Database using Show Tables Query

Tags: database, mysql

This query when runs always create logs for Database error. It works fine when table exists, but when it does not it generates the below shown debug logs.

Any alternative way to check if database table exists or to avoid these errors from filling up the debug logs file?

```
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
    // do something
}
```

Debug Logs:

```
[09-Sep-2018 12:21:50 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'splivemain_db.wp_survey_popup_form' doesn't exist for query DESCRIBE wp_survey_popup_form; made by do_action('omxl-logger_page_omxl-cf7'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, myplugin__Logger->display, myplugin__Logger->get_columns

[09-Sep-2018 12:21:50 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'splivemain_db.wp_survey_popup_form' doesn't exist for query DESCRIBE wp_survey_popup_form; made by do_action('omxl-logger_page_omxl-cf7'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, myplugin__Logger->display, myplugin__Logger->get, myplugin__Logger->get_columns

[09-Sep-2018 12:21:50 UTC] WordPress database error Table 'splivemain_db.wp_survey_popup_form' doesn't exist for query SELECT* FROM wp_survey_popup_form WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY activity_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10 made by do_action('omxl-logger_page_omxl-cf7'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, myplugin__Logger->display, myplugin__Logger->get
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is working for me with no "WordPress database error" messages:

```php
if ( $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SHOW TABLES LIKE %s", $table_name ) ) === $table_name ) {
    error_log( 'Table exists' . ': ' . print_r( $table_name, true ) );
} else {
    error_log( 'Table does not exist' . ': ' . print_r( $table_name, true ) );
}
```

Comment: It's basically the same code..